# std::stringsteam seems to break std::cout

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cout, stringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
    
int main() {
    std::stringstream ss1;
    std::cout << "hello";
}
```

For some reason, on VSCode on my Windows PC, the `std::cout` won't output anything when I have an `std::stringstream` line present but when I remove the line the output works. On my MacBook Pro this code runs normally in VSCode however.

Comment: Normally `std::cout` should flush when the program ends. But your implementation might have a problem. Try adding `<< std::flush` or `<< std::endl` after `"hello"` to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Change it to `std::cout << "hello\n";`. Text streams need a newline at the end. You probably don't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does; a newline should be sufficient.

Comment: @chids *For some reason, on vscode* -- So the console is not an actual console, but a fake one, right?  Well, whatever the fake console gives you, that's what happens.  What if you ran the program on the command-line -- actually opening a command-prompt, typing in the name of the executable, hitting enter, and seeing what it does?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The std::cout will run if have the std::stringstream line removed so I know that it is not a console issue.

Comment: @PeteBecker unfortunately this does not work

Comment: @chids Did you do what I suggested, or just guessing what will happen?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux this does not work unfortunately

Comment: *on VSCode* -- Also, VSCode is not a C++ compiler.  What is the actual compiler being used to build your program?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the program has always worked in command prompt, my issue is why it doesnt run correctly in vscode and only runs when i remove the std::stringstream line

Comment: Maybe the fake command prompt is buggy?  Whatever it is, command-line programs are meant to be run from the command-line.  An IDE can fake the command-prompt all it wants, it isn't a real command prompt.  So any bugs in implementing the faux command-prompt, report it to the VSCode team, or see if there is an update.

Comment: Since placing the highly recommended newline at the end of the string doesn't seem to have worked for you, you are in non-Standard space. We'll need compiler, compiler version, compiler and the toolchain distribution (and probably its version) along with the VS code version to help sort this out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie im using g++ to compile

Comment: The difference may be in the terminal’s behavior rather than in the binary’s behavior.

Comment: @chids Yes, this has nothing to do with the binary -- it has everything to do with how the terminal that is created within the IDE behaves.  What would have been concerning is if you ran this from a real command line, and it still didn't work.  *Then* we can almost conclude it has something to do with the binary or C++ compiler.

Comment: As suggested by others, try opening a terminal window and running the program there. The console in your IDE might have a weird bug.

Comment: Are you certain the version with the `std::stringstream` is compiling and linking successfully?  Perhaps the compiler issues a warning about `ss1` being declared and initialized but not referenced, and perhaps the compiler is set to treat warnings as errors.  So when you try to run, you're running some leftover executable (or nothing at all).  Just a theory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I ran it in terminal and the same problem still occurs.

Comment: I've noticed that there must be an issue with my g++ compiler, I have just resorted to using an alternative to stringstream in the mean time.